# Joomla - "Hello World - Hello" module

Tags: php, joomla, module

I successfully created a the simple joomla module from joomla.org tutorial

http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_create_a_module

Now I would like to add it as a restricted menu item in the "User Menu"

How would I do this? What Menu Item Type should I use?

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Go to joomla admin,

Create a new menu item.

You will find the option for access level at the bottom side of the page.

I have not use the `"Special"` access level so i don't know that whats it doing but if you select the `"Registered"` then this menu item will display only when any user is logged in to the site.

Comment: The Special access level includes users like Authors, Editors, and Publishers who have privileges above normal registered users.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly OT: There is a quite good book on Jommla! extension development, ***Learning Joomla! 1.5 Extension Development.***, contains (among others) topic on a menu development.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, but my book actually doesn't cover menu development. It does cover module development though.